# Behavioral inconsistency in the badges on the top bar

Tags: feature-request

The four badges on the right side of the top bar have inconsistent behavior. Specifically, the reviews/edits badge does not behave the same as the other three. When clicking on the others, an on-page pop-up appears beneath the bar; however, when clicking on the reviews/edits badge, you are taken to a completely separate page.

Is this an item that is on-radar and being addressed?